# NVDA ACCESIBILTY select box expanded/collapsed

Tags: reactjs, nvda

Nvda screen reader not showing expanded state for the select tag when the option size more than 9

But it's working only when options length is 9 Or less than 9

Need suggestions how to handle this scenario

Comment: Post a code example, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.